# Best practice for wrapping the body of ResponseEntity ajax style?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, generics

With `ResponseEntity` we have direct control over the HTTP response; we can set the headers, body and HTTP response code. And let's say on the client side we have a generic AJAX data service that is expecting three response status conditions: `success`, `fail`, and `error` - this status will be evaluated separately from the HTTP status code, which is of course taken care of by `$.ajax`. As a result, we need a generic object of some sort for the body of `ResponseEntity`, maybe something like the below, where `data` in `JsonResponse` is whatever piece of data the client requested; a list of users, a map of arbitrary data, anything (more on this in a second):

**ResponseEntityFactory.java**

```
public class ResponseEntityFactory {

    private enum ResponseStatus {
        SUCCESS, FAIL, ERROR
    }

    public static ResponseEntity success (String message, Object data) {
        return getResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK, ResponseStatus.SUCCESS, message, data, null);
    }

    /* ADDITIONAL SUCCESS, FAIL, ERROR FACTORY METHODS */

    private static ResponseEntity getResponseEntity(HttpStatus httpStatus, ResponseStatus responseStatus, String message, Object data, HttpHeaders headers) {

        if (httpStatus == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("HttpStatus cannot be null");
        if (responseStatus == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("ResponseStatus cannot be null");

        JsonResponse jsonResponse = new JsonResponse(responseStatus, message, data);
        return new ResponseEntity(jsonResponse, headers, httpStatus);
    }

    private static class JsonResponse {

        private ResponseStatus status;
        private String message;
        private Object data;

        public JsonResponse(ResponseStatus status, String message, Object data) {
            if (status == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("ResponseStatus cannot be null");
            this.status = status;
            this.message = message;
            this.data = data;
        }

        public ResponseStatus getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(ResponseStatus status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public Object getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(Object data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

    }

}
```

**ExampleController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/example")
public class ExampleController {

    @Autowire
    private UserService userService;        

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity getUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
        return AjaxResponseFactory.success("Found users", userList);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/active/{id}" method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity isUserActive(long userId) {
        boolean = userService.isUserActive(userId);
        return AjaxResponseFactory.success(null, boolean);
    }
}
```

The `ResponseEntityFactory` simplifies the controller, but my entire concern for this question centers around the `data` variable (of type `Object`) in `JsonResponse` - it smells. From the testing I've done so far, everything is serializing correctly: single primitives, to simple lists of `String` or `Long`, to more complex domain objects. So my question is, is this okay? Is there an alternative? An opportunity to somehow use `generics<T>`?

Again, the main goal is to be able to evaluate the HTTP response code separately from a response status code of `success`, `fail`, `error` - which in itself allows for greater granularity when reacting to the server's response. For instance, it's possible a `fail` condition to be returned with an `HTTP 200 OK`; the HTTP request was successful, it'd be inappropriate to set it otherwise, however there was a validation error (maybe a null username or something), which disallowed the action on the server. It could be argued that these types scenarios are technically of type `400 Bad Request`, but I tend to agree with folks that, even with the latest RFC `400` definition, these statuses should be associated to legitimate malformed requests, and not an necessarily and arbitrary issue with business logic.

So, what's the best way to ensure proper serialization of the `data` object if I'd like to respond to the browser with a `JsonResponse` type object within `ResponseEntity`? I'm open to any suggestions or alternatives - not tied to this at all, just seemed like a reasonable approach. But I'd be interested to see if solving this with generics would be feasible and/or more desirable.

Comment: An endpoint that returns different data types is kind of meh. Otherwise, why generics? The other side of the http communication can't see that the text it gets came from `ResponseEntity<JsonResponse<List<String> getResponseEntity(...`. For json serializers, everything is just an `Object` anyways (e.g. : https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString%28java.lang.Object%29 )

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm not sure I'm understanding your first point about different data types. Would the above be doing that if each Controller was using the EntityResponseFactory? And wrt generics, I assumed it might have been a better approach to outright using java.lang.Object in a List<T> versus List<Object> type of way, but my understanding could be misguided; limited knowledge of generics, and how they'd be consumed in the UI. And I think your last point might answer my question, everything is object anyway, so what's the harm here right?

Comment: In most cases, I'd be returning a list of domain or DTO objects as opposed to a list of String, hence the added concern over serialization

Comment: wrt types: when a single method can return `List<String>`, next time some DomainObject. Would be ugly as API to consume from `$.ajax` because there is not a fixed json schema. You could do that with `ResponseEntity`. I guess you don't want to though. - Object vs nicely specified: that's mostly interesting for you to see what your methods return. A few tools like json documentation auto generators may require that too. The serializer on the other hand rarely cares. Because even with generics, e.g. a `List<Number>` it has to check the concrete type and see if it has to do special serialization.

Comment: Ahh, I think I necessarily caused confusion by using a getData() method as my example in the Controller - I updated the question with a more real-world example of how my controller would look. And I would of course have a Controller for each applicable end-point (/users, /admin, etc), each having methods that would be descriptive and not anything like getData(). Also, for the JS side, there's a corresponding JS service for each end-point (user_service.js, admin_service.js), all of course utilize the more generic data_service for carrying out the ajax call.

Comment: Overall, just interested in any downsides to using the factory like this, where I just pass any data I want and hope it serializes appropriately, which it does seem to do, but I'm not sending bytes or images or anything. At any rate, it looks like I need to read up on serialization, thanks for the responses!